# Getting the Unity iOS Splash Screen

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

My app has splash screens of varying sizes for different iOS devices.  They are registered in the Unity PlayerSettings for iOS under 'iPhone 3.5"/Retina', 'iPhone 5.5" Landscape/Retina', etc.

My first scene is a loading scene that should look exactly like the splash screen (more initialization is going on under the hood).

I want to grab the splash screen asset that was used and place it in my loading scene, but I'm not sure how to determine exactly which asset was used.

I suppose I could build a lookup table keyed on strings returned by `SystemInfo.DeviceModel`, but that seems fragile.  I'd much rather use however Unity determines which splash screen to display, but I haven't been able to find how that happens.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Check the device resolution

You could check for the device resolution using `Screen.width` and `Screen.height`:

- iPhone 3.5": 480 x 320 / 960 x 640 (retina)
- iPhone 4": 1136 x 640
- iPhone 4.7": 1334 x 750
- iPhone 5.5": 2208 x 1242
- iPad: 1024x768 / 2048 x 1536 (retina)

### 2. Use the same image for all devices

I don't know how's your splash screen set up. But what I did on a previous project was to use the same image for all devices. Basically I just used the 4:3 (iPad (retina)) version and made a script that scaled it to fit it's width and just cut of the top and bottom area on devices with a wider screen.
Depending on your GUI system you may just anchor the image to the edges of the screen.